# Use bash string to provide multiple arguments to a program, where some argument include whitespace

Tags: bash, whitespace

When writing a script that calls `wget`, I want to make use of a variable that holds all of the headers, but if I attempt the following, then the whitespace within the header strings breaks them into multiple parameters (not a single header):

```
HEADERS='--header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"'
wget $HEADERS "$URL"
# ... $HEADERS is interpreted as 4 strings instead of 2 ...
wget --header Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate http://example.com
```

I can't wrap `$HEADERS` in quotation marks because I need it to be interpreted as 2 arguments instead of 1. (And if I had many headers in the variable, it would need to be split into still more arguments.)

I often write bash scripts that assemble arguments for other programs, and I often encounter this issue. Is there a solution in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a regular variable; use an array.

```
headers=(--header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate")
wget "${headers[@]}" "$URL"
```